# Trigonometric function on modulus function

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin x + \cos x = a$, then how do I get value of modulus of $\sin  x - \cos  x$, value in terms of $a$

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $|\sin x-\cos x|^2=(\sin x-\cos x)^2=(\sin x+\cos x)^2-4\sin x \cos x$

Observe that $(\sin x+\cos x)^2=a^2$ and $1+2\sin x \cos x=a^2$

So $|\sin x-\cos x|^2=a^2-2(a^2-1)=2-a^2$

Therefore $|\sin x-\cos x|=\sqrt {2-a^2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x+\cos x=a\implies (\sin x+\cos x)^2=a^2$$

$$\implies \left(\sin ^2 x+\cos^2 x\right)+2\sin x\cos x=a^2$$

$$\implies 2\sin x\cos x=a^2-1$$

$$|\sin x-\cos x|=\sqrt{(\sin x-\cos x)^2}$$

$$=\sqrt{\left(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x\right)-2\sin x\cos x}=\sqrt{(1)-\left(a^2-1\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we have $$\sin x+\cos x=a$$
$$(\sin x+\cos x)^2=a^2$$
$$\sin^2 x+\cos^2x+2\sin x\cos x=a^2$$
$$2\sin x\cos x=a^2-1$$
Now, one should have

$$(\sin x-\cos x)^2=(\sin x+\cos x)^2-4\sin x\cos x$$
$$(\sin x-\cos x)^2=(a)^2-2(a^2-1)$$$$(\sin x-\cos x)^2=2-a^2$$
$$|\sin x-\cos x|=\sqrt{2-a^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

hint use identity $(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab$ first find out $2 sin(x)cos(x)$. By squaring the given relation you get $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)+2sin(x)cos(x)=a^2$ thus $2 sin(x)cos(x)=a^2-1$ plug these values and get the required answer